# choco install ERROR: System must be an owning system

Tags: powershell, installation, chocolatey

Presently, I am attempting to install a [chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/) package in powershell as an administrator:

```
PS C:\Temp> choco install .\my-test-package.nupkg
```

But am receiving this error:

```
ERROR: System must be an owning system
The install of my-test-package was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\my-test-package.nupkg\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

This is what I see in `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log`:

```
2023-03-10 16:50:44,672 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to create directory "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - There was no original file at 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.files'
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.arguments".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.extra".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.version".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.sxs".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\.chocolatey\my-test-package\.pin".
2023-03-10 16:50:44,687 41472 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'HandlePackageResultCompletedMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2023-03-10 16:50:44,703 41472 [ERROR] - The install of my-test-package was NOT successful.
2023-03-10 16:50:44,703 41472 [ERROR] - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\my-test-package\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2023-03-10 16:50:44,703 41472 [DEBUG] - Moving 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\my-test-package'
 to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib-bad\my-test-package'
2023-03-10 16:50:46,719 41472 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2023-03-10 16:50:46,719 41472 [INFO ] - 
2023-03-10 16:50:46,719 41472 [ERROR] - Failures
2023-03-10 16:50:46,734 41472 [ERROR] -  - my-test-package (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\my-test-package\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
2023-03-10 16:50:46,734 41472 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2023-03-10 16:50:46,766 41472 [DEBUG] - Exiting with -1
```

Also, after researching [Chocolatey Troubleshooting](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/troubleshooting) I haven't found anything useful yet.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the full log https://pastebin.com/Yv2UN8en

This is the part of the `chocolateyInstall.ps1` that is failing, where essentially it is failing because the query on a `$dataset` is returning null:

```
function ThrowExceptionIfNotOwningSystem () {
  $result = IsOwningSystem
  if ($result -ne $true) {
    Throw "System must be an owning system"
  }
}

function IsOwningSystem () {
  $parameters = @()
  try {
    if (Get-Command "Get-PackageParameters") {
      $parameters = Get-PackageParameters
      $dataset = $parameters['DATASET']
      $table = "doas_privilege"
      $mode = "Primary"
      $sql = "SELECT system, owns FROM $table WHERE (mode = '$mode' and dataset = '$dataset');"
      $result = ExecuteSQLCommand $sql
      $owning = $result.owns
      $systemName = $result.system

      if ($owning -eq $null) {
        LogMessage "DATASET '$($dataset)' does not exist in database"
        return $false
      }
      elseif ($owning -eq "no"){
        LogMessage "$($systemName) system does not own '$($dataset)' dataset"  
        return $false
      }
      else{
        return $true   
      }
    }
  }
  catch {
    LogError "Failed to get commandline parameters"
  }  

}
```

The odd thing is that if I login to the database directly and perform a query it clearly returns results so the `$dataset` does exist on the server:

```
ISQL> SELECT system, owns FROM user_privilege WHERE (mode = 'Primary' and dataset = 'PRA');
system  owns

devserver25  yes

Rows selected = 1
SQL: Operation successful.
Elapsed time 0 ms.
Elapsed time: Prepare 0 ms.      Execute 0 ms.   Fetch results 0 ms.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to debug this `chocolateyInstall.ps1` script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that a test dataset could not be found because I was trying to perform the installation in a generic `PowerShell` command window when in fact I should have been using an application vendor-specific `PowerShell` window where they have added extra items to the system path, etc, with an `/s` flag where this flag means that it is installing the package from the local filesystem:

```
[VendorAppName]: PS C:\Temp> choco install /s . my-test-package
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule something out, can I get you to try the following:

```
choco install my-test-package --source .
```

rather than:

```
choco install .\my-test-package.nupkg
```

You should have actually received a warning when attempting to install by passing a direct path to the nupkg file.

In addition, it would be helpful if you can share the chocolateyInstall.ps1 file that you are trying to use, as well as the complete log file from the installation attempt, rather than only a snippet.